# Using xamarin, received a error message when i build/ debug my solutions. What's wrong?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

Re do a new solution and the error is still there.
looking to resintall xamarin studio.

/Desktop/mobileApp/mobileApp/Main.storyboard: Error: 2016-01-08 12:21:48.746 ibtoold[669:11689] [MT] DVTAssertions: ASSERTION FAILURE in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEInterfaceBuilder/IDEInterfaceBuilder-9531/InterfaceBuilderKit/Document/Model/IBMemberPropertyStorage.m:250

Details:   must be a candidate of ibDesignableContentView.ibShadowedSubviews to be an explicit value
Object:   
Method:   -setBits:forToManyRelationship:inConfiguration:
Thread:   {number = 1, name = main}

Hints: None
Backtrace:
  0  0x000000010f23ac2d -[DVTAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in DVTFoundation)
  1  0x000000010f23a761 _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2  0x000000010f23a978 _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3  0x00000001103a701f -[IBMemberPropertyStorage setBits:forToManyRelationship:inConfiguration:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  4  0x00000001103ac2e5 __93-[IBMemberPropertyStorage unarchiveBitsForToManyRelationship:inConfiguration:withUnarchiver:]_block_invoke_2 (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  5  0x000000011030cfcc -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  6  0x000000011030e627 __76-[IBDocumentUnarchiver registerDelayedReferenceUnarchivingOfType:withBlock:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  7  0x000000011030e28a -[IBDocumentUnarchiver enableUnarchivingReferencesOfType:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  8  0x00000001102968d4 -[IBDocument unarchivePlatformIndependentDataWithUnarchiver:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
  9  0x00000001104f3f6b -[IBStoryboardDocument unarchivePlatformIndependentDataWithUnarchiver:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 10  0x000000011029622d -[IBDocument unarchiveDocumentWithUnarchiver:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 11  0x000000011030d7df __48-[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 12  0x000000011030cfcc -[IBDocumentUnarchiver recurseWithElement:kind:invokingBlock:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 13  0x000000011030d31b -[IBDocumentUnarchiver unarchiveDocument:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 14  0x000000011028d84b __61-[IBDocument decodeContentsOfURL:ofType:decodingStyle:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 15  0x00000001102e2094 -[IBDocumentAutolayoutManager ignoreAutolayoutStatusInvalidationDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 16  0x00000001102c2b4c -[IBDocument ignoreAutolayoutStatusInvalidationDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 17  0x000000011028d5d7 -[IBDocument decodeContentsOfURL:ofType:decodingStyle:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 18  0x000000011028788c __39-[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:]_block_invoke (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 19  0x00000001102be072 -[IBDocument suppressAndResetUndoManagerDuring:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 20  0x0000000110287594 -[IBDocument readFromURL:ofType:error:] (in IDEInterfaceBuilderKit)
 21  0x000000010efe1168 (in ibtoold)
 22  0x000000010efda090 (in ibtoold)
 23  0x000000010efe2853 (in ibtoold)
 24  0x000000010efe63ae (in ibtoold)
 25  0x000000010efe6a62 (in ibtoold)
 26  0x000000010efe6939 (in ibtoold)
 27  0x000000010efd5bb7 (in ibtoold)
 28  0x000000010efe5fa3 (in ibtoold)
 29  0x000000010efe5208 (in ibtoold)
 30  0x00007fff9bba15ad start (in libdyld.dylib) (mobileApp)

Comment: R u serious ... this question can get an upvote ?? Hey Upvoter!! Please tell me only one reason that you liked this question.

Comment: Can you please elaborate your problem in detail?

Comment: I'm using xamarin.ios to build a mobile app. After completing the interface, i run and debug it on the simulator when I get a build error message on main.storyboard file and path. 
Before this error happen, I accidentally name a new class in the view controller properties and deleted away the .cs file, wonder if it is because of that.
Will reinstalling xamarin studio help fix the problem?